# Jenkins - Can't see my shell script's logs

Tags: shell, logging, jenkins

**EDIT:**
Ok, so after answer from [Vasanta Koli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3327358/vasanta-koli), I've looked deep in builds.
And actually, I have found the full console output.

It's a bit weird at first because you need to go in Build history or use the little arrow after your build name to access it... at the same place that "basic" console output when you click directly on your build's name.

Anyway, I can finally access to my full logs !

**Original question:**

This question may just look dumb, but in my Jenkins' configuration, I can't see all the logs from the shell script of my build.

I've looked an option to activate it, but I can't find it.

In my script, I'm just restoring a database, with an echo before each command, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

timestamp=$(date +%T)

echo $timestamp "- Delete"
dropdb -h localhost -U user database

echo $timestamp "- Creation"
createdb -h localhost -E unicode -U user database

echo $timestamp "- Restore"
pg_restore -h localhost -U user -O -d database database.tar
```

All the script is executed, but no logs in my build, in the web UI (Console output)
I'm obviously missing something here.

Can someone help me ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make variable for timestamp if you need actual time of the task (command) execution

also if you want logs to be redirected, then mention it.

---

It should be something like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logfile=/var/log/script.log

{
echo $(date +%T) "- Delete" 
dropdb -h localhost -U user database 

echo $(date +%T) "- Creation" 
createdb -h localhost -E unicode -U user database 

echo $(date +%T) "- Restore" 
pg_restore -h localhost -U user -O -d database database.tar 
} >> $logfile
```

Please check and update

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! At first, it was a function this is why it was a variable... !